# How to change the name of an extensionless file

Tags: windows, registry, file-extension

I had a stupid adware infection with my computer a while ago and while this is fixed now, it still has left some artifacts behind. Namely that the extentionless files (normally called "File") are now called savinshop.

I was looking around on the windows registry and I found (under Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts) the entry for the . file and I assumed that this was the extentionless file. It had (under \OpenWithList) a binary value key with the name 'savinshop'. I hoped that by renaming this key to 'File' it would solve the issue, but then they were called 'URL: File Protocol' or something like that. Then I compared it to the registry on my laptop (which wasn't infected), but they have no such keys. I proceeded to remove the keys as they were on my laptop, but now they are back to 'savinshop'. I was hoping someone would know how I can solve this issue.

Both my laptop and pc are on windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Open Command Prompt (running normally, if that doesn't work try as admin) in the directory with your extensionless file. Let's say it's named virus:

```
C:\>move virus virus.txt
   1 file(s) moved.
```

If this doesn't work try scanning with [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com/mwb-download) or your default antivirus.

Comment: Well that is an answer to a question I did not ask. The question was how to edit the name of the extensionless file type, not edit the extension of a specific extensionless file.

Comment: @INGIE Then just do the same, but replace "virus.txt" with the new name of the file

Comment: Please read my question carefully, it's the name of the file type, not the name of the file. I know how to rename files. The name of the file can for example be "sheet.xlsx", but the name of the file type is "Microsoft Excel Worksheet". It's the latter I want to change.